# Measurability of the floor function

Tags: measure-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions, measurable-functions, borel-sets

Let $u(x)=⌊x⌋$, i.e  the largest integer not greater than $x$ . Determine $\{u≥a\}$ for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$. Show that $u$ is Borel-measurable. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: What have you tried, what are your thoughts? What to you know about measurability of monotone functions?

Comment: @PhoemueX The monotone angle seems the easiest way... one can use the answer of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252421/are-monotone-functions-borel-measurable

Comment: Whenever I'm not wrong, for $v(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor$, $v^{-1}([c, \infty)) = [\lceil c \rceil, \infty)$ and for $u(x) = \lceil c \rceil$, $u^{-1}((c, \infty)) = (\lfloor c \rfloor, \infty)$, for every $c \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 4):

An idea to show that $u$ is measurable is that you can express a floor function as a simple one (a limit of simple functions)

$$ u(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty n \, \chi_{[n,n+1)}(x)$$

alternatively $u^{-1}[a,\infty) = \{ x \mid a \leq \lfloor x \rfloor \} = [ \lfloor a \rfloor +1 , \infty)$

EDIT: it is not right $u^{-1}[a,\infty) = [\lceil a \rceil,\infty)$

EDIT:Mainly intuition... i know that if there is an expression for it, it must be an interval written in terms of $a$ , and some type of roof or ceil function. For the proof

$$ a \leq \lfloor x \rfloor \implies  \lceil a \rceil \leq \lfloor x \rfloor  \leq x$$

$$ \lceil a \rceil  \leq x \implies a \leq \lceil a \rceil  \leq \lfloor x \rfloor $$

Comment: How do you deduce the interval in the last equality?

Comment: It was wrong... added an edit