# Showing that the function $f+g$ is Borel measurable

Tags: measure-theory, borel-measures

Given that two functions $f$ and $g$ from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$, such that $f$ is non-increasing and $g$ is non-decreasing.  How does one show that the function $f+g$ is Borel measurable?

Comment: I haven't bought the book yet, since the semester hasn't started yet. I am just trying to get a head start in this course of mine. Are you going to contribute with an help hand or just pointing fingers?

Comment: have a look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/252421/144410

Comment: Thank you, but i just got more confused.

Comment: If f and g are both Borel measurable, then the sum is also (known theorem).

Comment: @herbsteinberg, can you link me the theorem or refer me where to find it?

Comment: Could anyone perhaps provide me a suitable solution with justifying steps?

Comment: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/measure_theory/measure_notes_ch3.pdf   https://sites.ualberta.ca/~rjia/Math417/Notes/chap5.pdf  Google "sum of borel measurable functions" to get others.