# Showing that a function f+g is Borel measurable

Tags: measure-theory

I'm working on the following problem. I have found some definitions, that I think I can use. But I'm unsure how to implement them logically, so hope someone can help me proceed.

Problem:

Let f : R → R be a function such that f(x) ≤ f(y) for all x ≤ y, and let g : R → R
be a function such that g(x) ≥ g(y) for all x ≤ y. Show that the function f + g is Borel
measurable.

My attempt:

Using the proposition (X, A) is a measurable space, f , g ∈ M. Then f ± g are also measurable

Using the concept of monotiniticy since we have:

f(x) ≤ f(y) for all x ≤ y and g(x) ≥ g(y) for all x ≤ y

Comment: Indeed, it suffices to show that $f$ and $g$ are both measurable. This follows from monotonicity as you can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/229497/f-mathbfr-rightarrow-mathbfr-monotone-increasing-rightarrow-f-is).

Comment: Thank you. So If I simply show that the functions are monotone (f(x) ≤ f(y) for all x ≤ y and g(x) ≥ g(y) for all x ≤ y) then they are Borel measurable?

Comment: So, it is basically this I have to apply?: "If f is increasing, the set {x:f(x)>a} is an interval for all a, hence measurable."

Comment: [Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2892369/showing-that-the-function-fg-is-borel-measurable) with same title