# Monotone functions are Borel-measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions, measurable-sets

I know that there are many similar questions to mine. But this is more a question concerning a certain "logic".

I want to show, that every monotone function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Borel-measurable.
Via definition of Borel-measurability, it suffices to show, that $$\forall y \in \mathbb{R}: \{f \geq y\} \in \mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R}). $$

*Proof*:

Let wlog $f$ be a non-increasing function and $y \in \mathbb{R}$ fix.

(1)  If $\{f \geq y \}  = \emptyset$ than $\{f \geq y \} \in \mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R}) $

(2) If $\{f \geq y \}  \neq \emptyset $ define $x^* :=\sup\{x \in \mathbb{R}: f(x) \geq y \} $. Than we have:

- $x^* = \infty \Rightarrow \{ f \geq y \} = \mathbb{R} \in \mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R}) $
- $x^* < \infty$:

  - $x^* \in \{ f \geq y \} \Rightarrow \{f \geq y \} = (- \infty, x^*] \in \mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R}) $
  - $x^* \notin \{ f \geq y \} \Rightarrow \{f \geq y \} = (- \infty, x^*) \in \mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R}) $

Since all these sets are in $\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}$ arbitrary $\Rightarrow$ $f$ is measurable.

I hope that this is so far okay. But I am not really happy with the last distinction: How is it even possible, that  $x^* \notin \{ f \geq y \}$, since $f$ is a non-increasing function? I have a hard time thinking about this trivial fact; some help would be awesome!

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful to add the following: "Let $f$ be a non-increasing function. Fix a number $y\in \mathbb{R}$."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is fine. Let $f(x)=0$ for $x<0$ and $f(x)=-1$ if $x \geq 0$. Take $y=0$. Then $\{x: f(x) \geq y\}=(-\infty, 0)$ and $x^{*}=0$.