# If $(\kappa_t)$ is a Markov semigroup, is $t\mapsto\left\|\kappa_tf\right\|_\infty$ Borel measurable?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(E,\mathcal E)$ be a measurable sapce, $$\mathcal E_b:=\left\{f:E\to\mathbb R\mid f\text{ is bounded and }\mathcal E\text{-measurable}\right\}$$ be equipped with the surepmum norm and $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a Markov semigroup on $(E,\mathcal E)$. Moreover, let $$(\kappa_tf)(x):=\int\kappa_t(x,{\rm d}y)f(y)\;\;\;\text{for }f\in\mathcal E_b.$$ Note that $$\kappa_tf\in\mathcal E_b\;\;\;\text{for all }f\in\mathcal E_b\tag1.$$

> If $f\in\mathcal E_b$, are we able to show that $$[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)\;,\;\;\;t\mapsto\left\|\kappa_tf\right\|_\infty\tag2$$ is Borel measurable? If not, are we able to impose a suitable assumption ensuring that?

Comment: If $t\mapsto \kappa_t f$ is Borel mble, then the projection should be universally mble. You may look at the Stochastic Optimal Control literature for precise statements.

Comment: @d.k.o. If $X$ is a random variable with values in a normed $\mathbb R$-vector space $M$, we usually need that $M$ is separable in order to show that the norm of $X$ is measurable as well. Don't you think we need this here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in fact the function $t \mapsto \|\kappa_t f\|_\infty$ is monotone decreasing, and [every monotone function is Borel](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252421/are-monotone-functions-borel-measurable).

The operator $\kappa_t$ is Markovian, and so $\|\kappa_t f\|_\infty \le \|f\|_\infty$.  To see this directly, note that for each $x$, the measure $\kappa_t(x, \cdot)$ is a probability measure, and therefore
$$|\kappa_t f(x)| =\left| \int f(y) \kappa_t(x,dy) \right| \le  \int |f(y) |\kappa_t(x,dy) \le \|f\|_\infty$$
then take the supremum over $x$.

Now for any $t > s$ we can use the semigroup property and the Markovian property of $\kappa_{t-s}$ to write
$$\|\kappa_t f\|_\infty = \|\kappa_{t-s} \kappa_{s} f\|_\infty \le \|\kappa_s f\|_\infty$$
and so the function $t \mapsto \|\kappa_t f\|_\infty$ is indeed monotone decreasing.

Comment: Is $t\mapsto\kappa_tf$ itself Borel measurable? I've asked separately for that: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4487877/47771. Would be great if you could  take a look.