# If $t\mapsto g(t)$ is a map into a function space and $t\mapsto g(t)(x)$ is measurable for all $x$, is $t\mapsto g(t)$ measurable as well?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(E,\mathcal E)$ be a measurable space, $$\mathcal E_b:=\{f:E\to\mathbb R\mid f\text{ is bounded and }\mathcal E\text{-measurable}\}$$ be equipped with the supremum norm and $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a Markov semigroup on $(E,\mathcal E)$. $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$ is a contraction semigroup on $\mathcal E_b$ via $$(\kappa_tf)(x):=\int\kappa_t(x,{\rm d}y)f(y)\;\;\;\text{for }x\in E\text{ and }f\in\mathcal E_b$$ for $t\ge0$.

> Let $f\in\mathcal E_b$. If $$[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R\;,\;\;\;t\mapsto(\kappa_tf)(x)\tag1$$ is Borel measurable for all $x\in E$, are we able to show that $$[0,\infty)\to\mathcal E_b\;,\;\;\;t\mapsto\kappa_tf\tag2$$ is Borel measurable as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The sup norm topology on $\mathcal{E}_b$ is just too large (strong).

Let $E = \mathbb{R}$ and consider the Markov semigroup of uniform motion to the right, i.e. $\kappa_t f(x) = f(x+t)$.  Then (1) is clearly satisfied.  Let $f(x) = 1_{x \ge 0}$ be a step function and note that $\|\kappa_s f - \kappa_t f\|_\infty = 1$ for all $s \ne t$.  Fix your favorite non-Borel subset $V \subset \mathbb{R}^+$, and consider the set $A = \{\kappa_t f : t \in V\}$.  As noted, this set is discrete in $\mathcal{E}_b$; in particular it is closed and Borel.  But its preimage under the map $t \mapsto \kappa_t f$ is $V$ and so (2) fails.