# If for a.e. $x \in X$ the sequence $(f_n(x, \cdot))_n$ is Cauchy in $L^1 (Y)$, then $(f_n)$ is Cauchy in $(L^0 (Z), \rho_Z)$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, cauchy-sequences, measurable-functions

Below we use [Bochner measurability](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bochner_measurable_function) and [Bochner integral](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bochner_integral). Let

- $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ and $(Y, \mathcal B, \nu)$ be *complete finite* measure spaces,
- $(E, | \cdot |)$ a Banach space,
- $S (X)$ the space of $\mu$-simple functions from $X$ to $E$,
- $L^0 (X)$ the space of $\mu$-measurable functions from $X$ to $E$,
- $L^1 (X)$ the space of $\mu$-integrable functions from $X$ to $E$,
- $Z := X \times Y$,
- $\mathcal C :=\mathcal A \otimes \mathcal B$ the product $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$,
- $\lambda := \mu \otimes \nu$ the product measure of $\mu$ and $\nu$,
- $(Z, \overline{\mathcal C}, \overline{\nu})$ the completion of $(Z, \mathcal C, \nu)$.

Let $\rho_Y$ be a [pseudometric](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Pseudometric_space#Definition)  on $L^0(Y)$ defined by
$$
\rho_Y (f, g) := \int_Y \min\{|f-g|, 1\} \, \mathrm d \nu
\quad \forall f, g \in L^0 (Y).
$$

We define $\rho_Z$ on $L^0(Z)$ similarly. *Theorem 4.4.1* at page 98 of Martin Väth's monograph [Ideal Spaces](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/BFb0093548) suggests that

> [Theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/a/452849/99469) Let $f_n \in L^0(Z)$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. Assume that for $\mu$-a.e. $x \in X$, the sequence $(f_n(x, \cdot))_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(L^1 (Y), \| \cdot\|_{L^1 (Y)})$. Then $(f_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(L^0 (Z), \rho_Z)$.

Could you have a check on my below attempt? Thank you so much for your help!

---

For simplicity, we write
$$
\nu (|f - g| > \delta) := \nu (\{y \in Y : |f (y) - g(y)| > \delta\})
\quad \forall \delta >0, \forall f,g \in L^0 (Y).
$$

Let $\hat \rho_Y$ be another pseudometric on $L^0(Y)$ defined by
$$
\hat \rho_Y (f, g) := \inf_{\delta >0} \{ \nu (|f - g| > \delta)  +\delta \}
\quad \forall f, g \in L^0 (Y).
$$

We have some useful properties, i.e.,

> **Lemma 1** $(L^0(Y), \rho_Y)$ is complete.
>
> **Lemma 2** $(L^0(Y), \hat \rho_Y)$ is complete.
>
> **Lemma 3** The following statements are equivalent:
>
> - (S1) $\rho_Y (f_n, f) \to 0$.
> - (S2) Every subsequence of $(f_n)$ has a further subsequence that converges to $f$ $\nu$-a.e.
> - (S3)  $f_n \to f$ in measure, i.e.,
>   $$
>   \nu (\{y \in Y : |f_n (y)-f(y)| > \varepsilon\}) \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0
>   \quad \forall \varepsilon>0.
>   $$
> - (S4) $\hat \rho_Y (f_n, f) \to 0$.
>
> *Proof*
>
> 1. The proof of the completeness of $\rho_Y$ can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4753822/the-metric-space-l0-x-rho-of-mu-measurable-functions-is-complete).
> 2. The proof of the completeness of $\hat\rho_Y$ can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4754648/the-metric-hat-rho-f-g-inf-delta-0-mu-f-g-delta-del).
> 3. The proof of (S1) $\iff$ (S2) can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4753838/a-characterization-of-convergence-in-the-metric-space-l0-x-rho-of-mu). The proof of (S3) $\iff$ (S4) can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4754273/convergence-in-a-complete-finite-measure-is-metrizable). The proof of (S1) $\iff$ (S3) can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4753870/a-characterization-of-convergence-in-a-finite-measure).

Now we are going to prove our theorem. Assume the contrary that $(f_n)$ is not a Cauchy sequence in $(L^0 (Z), \rho_Z)$. By above **Lemmas** $(f_n)$ is not a Cauchy sequence in $(L^0 (Z), \hat \rho_Z)$. There is $\varepsilon >0$ and two subsequences $\varphi, \psi$ of $\mathbb N$ such that
$$
\hat \rho_Z (f_{\varphi (n)}, f_{\psi (n)}) \ge \varepsilon
\quad \forall n \in \mathbb N.
$$

Then
$$
\lambda (|f_{\varphi (n)} - f_{\psi (n)}| > \delta)  +\delta \ge \varepsilon
\quad \forall n \in \mathbb N, \forall \delta >0.
$$

We pick $\delta := \varepsilon/2$ and get
$$
\lambda (|f_{\varphi (n)} - f_{\psi (n)}| > \varepsilon/2)  \ge \varepsilon/2
\quad \forall n \in \mathbb N.
$$

Let $g_n := f_{\varphi (n)} - f_{\psi (n)}$. Then $g_n \in L^0(Z)$. We define
$$
h_n: X \to \mathbb R, x \mapsto \| g_n (x, \cdot) \|_{L^1 (Y)}.
$$

It has been [verified](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/452805/is-there-a-modification-of-f-on-a-null-set-such-that-f-0-t-to-lp-mat) that the map $x \mapsto g_n (x, \cdot)$ belongs to $L^0 (X, L^1(Y))$. Hence $h_n$ indeed belongs to $L^0 (X, \mathbb R)$. By our assumption, $h_n \to 0$ $\mu$-a.e.

> [Lemma 3.1.3.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4754895/if-rho-x-g-n-0-mathbb-r-to-0-then-rho-z-f-n-0-e-to-0) Let $g_n \in L^0(Z)$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$ such that for $\mu$-a.e. $x \in X$ we have $(g_n(x, \cdot))_n \subset L^1(Y)$. We define
> $$
> h_n: X \to \mathbb R, x \mapsto \| g_n (x, \cdot) \|_{L^1 (Y)}.
> $$
> If $\rho_{X} (h_n, 0_\mathbb R) \to 0$ then $\rho_Z (g_n, 0_E) \to 0$.

By **Lemma 3.1.3.**, $g_n \to 0$ in measure, which is a contradiction. This completes the proof.