# Convergence in marginal measure implies that in product measure

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

Let

- $T>0$ and $p \in [1, \infty)$,
- $X :=[0, T]$ and $Y:= \mathbb R^d$,
- $\cal A$ the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra of $X$,
- $\cal B$ the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra of $Y$,
- $\mu, \nu$ *complete finite* measures on $X, Y$ respectively,
- $\mu, \nu$ absolutely continuous,
- $Z :=X \times Y$,
- $\cal C$ the product $\sigma$-algebra of $\cal A$ and $\cal B$,
- $\lambda$ the product measure of $\mu$ and $\nu$,
- $(Z, \overline{\mathcal C}, \overline{\lambda})$ the completion of $(Z, \mathcal C, \lambda)$,
- $L^0 (X) := L^0 (X, \mathbb R)$ the space of measurable functions from $X$ to $\mathbb R$.

Let $L^p_{\text{loc}} (Y)$ be the space of measurable functions $f:Y \to \mathbb R$ such that
$$
\|f\|_{L^p_{\text{loc}}} := \sup_{y \in Y} \|1_{B(y, 1)} f\|_{L^p} < \infty,
$$
where $B(y, 1)$ is the open unit ball centered at $y$. Let $(y_m)$ be a countable dense subset of $Y$. The sphere is a $\nu$-null set. Then by dominated convergence theorem (DCT),
$$
\|f\|_{L^p_{\text{loc}}} = \sup_{m \in \mathbb N} \|1_{B(y_m, 1)} f\|_{L^p}
\quad \forall f \in L^p_{\text{loc}} (Y).
$$

Let $\rho_Z$ be a [pseudometric](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Pseudometric_space#Definition)  on $L^0(Z)$ defined by
$$
\rho_Z (f, g) := \int_Z \min\{|f-g|, 1\} \, \mathrm d \lambda
\quad \forall f, g \in L^0 (Z).
$$

Then convergence in $\rho_Z$ is equivalent to that [in measure](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Convergence_in_measure#Definitions).  We define $\rho_X$ on $L^0 (X)$ similarly. I'm trying to prove an analogue of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4754895/if-rho-x-g-n-0-mathbb-r-to-0-then-rho-z-f-n-0-e-to-0) result, i.e.,

> **Theorem** Let $f_n \in L^0(Z)$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$ such that for $\mu$-a.e. $x \in X$ we have $(f_n(x, \cdot))_n \subset L^p_{\text{loc}} (Y)$. We define
> $$
> g_n: X \to \mathbb R, x \mapsto \| f_n (x, \cdot) \|_{L^p_{\text{loc}}}.
> $$
> If $\rho_{X} (g_n, 0) \to 0$ then $\rho_Z (f_n, 0) \to 0$.

I have [verified](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4756754/assume-fx-cdot-in-lp-textloc-y-for-a-e-x-in-x-then-the-map) that $g_n$ indeed belongs to $L^0 (X)$. Could you have a check on my below attempt? Thank you so much for your help!

---

We define $c:[0, \infty] \to[0, 1]$ by
$$
c(m) := \inf \{\min\{ \| 1_{B} \|_{L^p_{\text{loc}}}, 1\} : B \in \mathcal{B} \text{ s.t. } \nu (B) \ge m\}.
$$

Then $c$ is non-decreasing and [thus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252421/are-monotone-functions-borel-measurable) Borel measurable. Clearly, $\| 1_{B} \|_{L^p_{\text{loc}}} \ge c (\nu (B))$ for all $B \in \cal B$. Let's verify $c(m)>0$ for all $m>0$. Assume the contrary that $c(m_0)=0$ for some $m_0>0$. There is a sequence $(B_n) \subset \cal B$ such that $\inf_n \nu(B_n) \ge m_0$ and $\| 1_{B_n} \|_{L^p_{\text{loc}}} \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0$. Then there [is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4756771/let-f-n-f-lp-textloc-to-0-there-is-a-subsequence-n-k-such-th) a subsequence $(n_k)$ such that $1_{B_{n_k}} \xrightarrow{k \to \infty} 0$ $\nu$-a.e. By dominated convergence theorem, $\nu (B_{n_k}) \xrightarrow{k \to \infty} 0$. This is a contradiction.

Let $\varepsilon >0$ and $M_n := \{ (x, y) \in Z: |f_n (x, y)| \ge \varepsilon \} \in \overline{\cal C}$. Then
$$
\begin{align*}
g_n (x)  &\ge \| \varepsilon 1_{M_n} (x, \cdot)\|_{L^p_{\text{loc}} (Y)} \\
&\ge \varepsilon c (\nu ( \{y \in Y : (x, y) \in M_n\} )) \\
&= \varepsilon c \bigg ( \int_Y 1_{M_n} (x, \cdot) \, \mathrm d \nu \bigg ).
\end{align*}
$$

Then $c  ( \int_Y 1_{M_n} (x, \cdot) \, \mathrm d \nu ) \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0$ in $\rho_X$. Then $c  ( \int_Y 1_{M_n} (x, \cdot) \, \mathrm d \nu ) \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0$ in measure. For any $\delta>0$, we have $c(\delta)>0$. So
$$
\mu \left ( \bigg \{x \in X : c \bigg ( \int_Y 1_{M_n} (x, \cdot) \, \mathrm d \nu \bigg ) \ge c(\delta) \bigg \}  \right ) \xrightarrow{n \to \infty}  0
\quad \forall \delta >0,
$$
which implies by monotonicity of $c$,
$$
\mu \left ( \bigg \{x \in X : \int_Y 1_{M_n} (x, \cdot) \, \mathrm d \nu  \ge \delta \bigg \} \right ) \xrightarrow{n \to \infty}  0
\quad \forall \delta >0,
$$
i.e., $\int_Y 1_{M_n} (x, \cdot) \, \mathrm d \nu \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0$ in measure. Dominated convergence theorem [also holds](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Convergence_in_measure#Properties) if almost everywhere convergence is replaced by convergence in measure. Then
$$
\int_X\int_Y 1_{M_n} (x, y) \, \mathrm d \nu (y) \, \mathrm d \mu (x) \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0,
$$
or equivalently $\lambda (M_n) \to 0$. The claim then follows.